# how to specify the labels size and position to create?

Tags: qt4, qpainter, qlabel

I'm creating label and displaying text on the label using paintevent. How to specify the size of the label and Qpoints to create the label in particular area?

Answer (score 0):

I got to know by searching on google..

```
label->setGeometry(QRect(x,y,width,height));
```